# How to get data by drop down list in html

Tags: html

I have created a drop down list in html (select element).I want to show the selected option somewhere else in the html how to get it [please see the image by clicking here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2u5QC.png). Could you please tell me how to get the result in front of class in "your id" part.

Comment: This is a dynamic behaviour. You need Javascript for this. Define a function that sets the value of some text (lookup html element by ID) and call it upon select's onchange event.
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `onchange` event of the select element and store this value in a variable, which you can display some place else

Answer (score 0):

Try using jQuery:

```
$("#selectbox_id option:selected").text();
```

and to get the selected option value

```
$("#selectbox_id option:selected").val();
```

> `selectbox_id` is the id attribute `<select id="">` of your select element

Source: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-get-the-text-value-of-a-selected-option/